# Resize container to window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function resizeGridIscroll(){
  var $windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var $windowHeight = $(window).height();

  var $itemHeight = $('.container').height();
  $('.container').css('min-height', $itemHeight - 1);
}

 $(window).resize(function(){
   resizeGridIscroll();
})
```

```css
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.bloc {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bloc bloc1"></div>
  <div class="bloc bloc2"></div>
  <div class="bloc bloc3"></div>
  <div class="bloc bloc4"></div> 
</div>
```

With this code structure, I would like the height of my container to shrink to resize the browser.

The js code works partially. The height of the container diminishes when we narrow our window, but it continues to shrink if our window becomes larger.

Is there a way to predict browser enlargement or shrinkage?

Thank you

### [Codepen avaiblable](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWLwRq)

Answer (score 1):

Since you set a `min-height` the height of the `.container` will remain on the second call of the `resizeGridIsScroll()`.

Try the following:

```
function resizeGridIscroll(){
  var $windowWidth = $(window).width(),
      $windowHeight = $(window).height(),
      $itemHeight;

  // reset the min-height of .container first
  $('.container').css('min-height', '');

  $itemHeight = $('.container').height();
  $('.container').css('min-height', $itemHeight - 1);
}
```

Comment: No... the container does not shrink in height when you resize the browser.

Comment: I don’t understand your code anyway. What exactly are you trying to do? This? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWxBXE

Comment: [Copen here.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWLwRq)



I want the height of my container to decrease when the user resizes his navigator. With my current codepen, you can see that the container reduces when the window is reduced. Conversely when it is enlarged, the container continues to shrink while it should grow (in height !!)

Comment: I’m giving up. Doesn’t make sense. Why would you get the height of `.container` just to set it as `min-height`? And why is `$windowHeight` not used? Sorry, I’m out. Take the Codepen or leave it.

Comment: I'm just explaining the result I want, my code is completely rotten, I know.

But your copen does not do anything at home. As much as if the js were empty. Or I missed something.